# NGINX rewrite args without an IF?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-config

I would like to rewrite legacy links using a query parameter type of URL to a new style of URL.

Ex.

1. `example.com/page?id=1` -> `example.com/page/1`
2. `example.com/otherpage?id=1` -> `example.com/otherpage/1`

Currently I have the following configuration using the [evil if](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

```
if ($args ~* "id=(.*)") {
  set $w1 $1;
  rewrite .* $scheme://$host/page/$w1? permanent;
}
```

*Note: I am using CloudFront, and relying on the host header above.*

If the above is in a server block, with no other location block - would this qualify as a non-evil use of `if` in NGINX config? Also, the above only supported `/page/`. Any better ideas for making that portion work for `otherpage` and other pages?

I have seen a few other ideas discussing using a map, but I'm not quite sure how to bring it all together? I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
map $args_id ?? {
  default ?
  ??
}

...
server {
   ...

   ???
   
}
```

UPDATE:
Based on the Answer from @Ivan, this was my final solution:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html index.htm;

  # Handle legacy requests
  if ($args ~* "id=(.*)") {
    set $w1 $1;
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host$uri/$w1? permanent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` construction isn't evil. You can use something like

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://$host$uri/$w1? permanent;
```

for any page. More complex example if you want to process both `example.com/page?id=1` and `example.com/page/?id=1`:

```
map $uri $maybe_slash {
    ~/$      "";
    default  "/";
}
...
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host$uri$maybe_slash$w1? permanent;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming that my use of IF was not evil, and helping me better understand the use of $uri in this context.

Comment: @shawnjohnson Although official documentation says that the only safe things you can use within the `if` block are `return ...` and `rewrite ... last`, in fact using `set` and `rewrite ... permanent` or `rewrite ... redirect` are ok too. What is really evil and could lead to unpredictable results is using any directive that isn't belongs to [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) (and you could see that both `set` and `rewrite` are directives from that module).